# Recode utf8..cp1250 outcome in iso-8859-1

Tags: shell, encoding, utf-8

I have CSV file that appears to be correctly encoded in UTF-8.

```
   iconv -f UTF-8 file.csv -o /dev/null  # returns 0
```

When I try to recode the file to cp1250 (tried recode/iconv even Perl), resulting file is encoded in iso-8859-1 - at least according to

```
   file -i resulting_file.csv
   resulting_file.csv: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Locale setting on the server is

```
   LANG=en_US.UTF-8
   LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_ALL=
```

I can´t figure out why. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iso-8895-1, iso-8895-15 and Windows-1252 (CodePage1252) character sets are very similar, only differing by a handful of characters and/or locations. For example, iso-8895-1 doesn't have a euro (€) symbol. Windows-1252 and -15 do, but it's mapped to different bytes.

`file` uses "magic" lookup to guess the encoding. If the characters that make those character sets differ don't exist in the text, then `file` can't differentiate between the three.

It certainly sounds like you have some non-ASCII Latin characters but not enough for `file` to know any difference.

You can rest easy though - your file is compatible with Windows-1252 encoding.

Comment: You are right, my CSV contains several Czech characters. When I force emacs to open the file in cp1250, it looks correct. I have worked a lot with text files in Linux, but this was my first case when the detection was wrong (I´m not speaking about malformed files). Thx for the answer.